# Angular aot build: dynamic forRoot parameter results in undefined

Tags: angular, ng-modules

I need to send a configuration (array of objects) to a service in a feature module and this configuration needs to be dynamically calculated. I used `forRoot` and it worked fine until I've built it with `--aot`.

**problem:** With `--aot`, the configuration results in `undefined`.

Here is a link to an example I made on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aot-forroot-error

**!! it works as desired on stackblitz, since it is not built with aot !!** If you build it locally with aot, though, the `GetConfigService` will throw an error since `config` will be undefined.

Important parts:

AppModule:

```
export const config = [
  {
    id: 'first'
  },
  {
    id: 'second'
  }
];

// just illustrative modification (in my project I need to modify config based on environment)
export function modifyConfig(config) {
  return config.map(c => c.id === 'first' ? {...c, default: true} : c);
}

const configModified = modifyConfig(config);

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    WithParametersdModule.forRoot(configModified)
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

WithParametersdModule:

```
@NgModule()
export class WithParametersdModule {
  static forRoot(config) {
    return {
      ngModule: WithParametersdModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: SOME_CONFIG,
          useValue: config
        },
        GetConfigService
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

GetConfigService:

```
@Injectable()
export class GetConfigService {

  constructor(@Inject(SOME_CONFIG) private config) {}

  get configObj() {
    if (!this.config) {
      throw `config: ${this.config}`;
    }

    return this.config;
  }
}
```

Thanks for help or explanation of what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I found that it might be because AOT would try to replace `useValue` at compile time but when you pass these values at runtime so AOT just replace it with `undefined`. The solution is use `useFactory` instead of `useValue`. This solved this problem.

Here is what I did:

```
// Declare a function type which returns the config
export type ConfigFunction = () => any;

// Replace useValue with useFactory
@NgModule()
export class WithParametersdModule {
  static forRoot(config: {
    func: ConfigFunction,
    // You could add other config parameters here...
  }) {
    return {
      ngModule: WithParametersdModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: SOME_CONFIG,
          useFactory: config.func
        },
        GetConfigService
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as following:

```
export function getConfig(): any {
  return {
    id: 'first'
  },
  {
    id: 'second'
  };
}

@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    WithParametersdModule.forRoot({ func: getConfig }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```