# How to Load Environment Data for app.modules.ts in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, configuration

I need to load data from a service which contains environment data.  I need some of that data for a module in `app.modules`.

Here's a small `app.modules.ts` example:

```
import { CustomEnvironmentService } from './CustomEnvironmentService';

let customService: CustomEnvironmentService;

@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [CustomModule.forRoot(customService.ENVIRONMENT_DATA)],
    providers: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

First thing to notice is that `customService.ENVIRONMENT_DATA` is just a public variable in `CustomEnvironmentService` which gets information from an environment config file called `env.js`.

The problem is that when the app loads `customService.ENVIRONMENT_DATA` is undefined.  This is understandable as I'm pretty sure the service isn't initialized and hasn't fetched the data.

I found something called `APP_INITIALIZER` but it appears that I may not be able to use it to read from either that `env.js` file or will it use my `CustomEnvironmentService` (which gets the data from `env.js`).

I'm also basing my implementation on this article: [How to use environment variables to configure your Angular application without a rebuild](https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/)

Any ideas?

Comment: customService.ENVIRONMENT_DATA type of variable? CustomModule is really custom or 3rd party module?

Comment: Can you provide the code for your `CustomEnvironmentService` then it will be easier to understand what is going on. Is this an Angular service or not?

Comment: What I'm looking for here is a json obj from a config file that gets injected into `CustomModule.forRoot(jsonData)`. CustomModule is pseudocode for a real module that requires a json configuration. I need that json to be configurable between environments.  `customService.ENVIRONMENT_DATA` is also pseudocode representing a possible service implementation- it doesn't have to be a service... it just has to load data into `CustomModule.forRoot({injected data here or globally})`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Using an `APP_INITIALIZER` would be my suggestion, as you've alluded to. Your question is asking what to do to load env data from a file (which the article you linked to answers), but you're not asking a question about a specific problem you're facing or any details about what you've tried.

Comment: @GeoffJames I already built the service to load data from an external file via that article.  I also played around with `APP_INIITALIZER`. The article does NOT load data from a file specifically for app.module.ts during load.  It's loading it AFTER app.module.ts has already loaded.  `APP_INITIALIZER` doesn't appear to allow me to load from that external file and into app.module.ts where I need it to go... which is `CustomModule.forRoot({json data from external file goes here})`. `APP_INITIALIZER` won't let me do this (unless you've got a solution I don't know about).

Comment: It's still not entirely clear what you're asking. How is your `CustomEnvironmentService` being set up? What did you try with `APP_INITIALIZER`? Without enough information as to what you're currently doing - so that we might be able to reproduce the issue you're having - we'd all just be stabbing in the dark.

Comment: Can you show what you want to do with the data in `CustomModule`? Do you provide it straight away in providers? If that's the case you might need to modify `CustomModule` to use a factory to retrieve the data instead of having it passed straight away. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131083/angular-aot-build-dynamic-forroot-parameter-results-in-undefined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the approach from the article you link you cannot use an `APP_INITIALIZER` because they get called after all the imported modules have initialized what you already discovered.

Since this approach just sets the environment settings as a global window property `__env` you can just define a global constant in Angular that you assign the value of the environment settings from the window. Then it will be available in all the application. This will be available also immediately when the application starts.

For example you create an `environment-data.ts` file with the following content:

```
export const ENVIRONMENT_DATA = window['__env'];
```

Then just import the constant where you need it and use it.

```
import { ENVIRONMENT_DATA } from './environment-data';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [CustomModule.forRoot(ENVIRONMENT_DATA)],
    providers: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the exact timings as to when it runs but you can read from a file using APP_INITIALIZER.

app.module.ts

```
export function startupServiceFactory(startupService: StartupService) {
    return () => startupService.load();
}

@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        StartupService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: startupServiceFactory,
            deps: [StartupService],
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
```

startup.service.ts

```
export class StartupService {
    // I just use private properties on the class to hold the returned values
    private localStartupData: any;

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}

    load(): any {
        // I'm returning a txt file so I have to set the responseType to text
        this.httpClient.get('<relativePathToFile>/env.js', { responseType: 'text' })
        .pipe(
            catchError((err) => {
                // If I have any defaults in case of file not existing I set them here
                return throwError(err);
            })
        )
        .toPromise()
        .then((data: any) => {
            this.localStartupData = data;
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
            Promise.resolve();
        });
    }

    get startupData(): any {
        return this.localStartupData;
    }
}
```

Just make sure that env.js is included in your angular.json

Comment: That won't work as the forRoot method will be called before I think

Comment: I don't know the timings either. It will work to read a file using APP_INITIALIZER though